# Validating SSIS package

Tags: ssis

If I create an SSIS package in SSDT that has an error of some sort, save the package, then close and reopen it, it will do validation upon opening the project and alert me of any errors. However, this is the only way I have found to find if I have any errors. If I simply click Build, it will do so without any errors, so this is not the same process as the initial validation. Do I really have to close out of the package and reopen in SSDT to get this functionality? The only other way I have seen is actually during runtime after executing the package. I'm looking for a way before execution.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Task Validations occurs when you open the package if you are working online. This is useful because it finds errors in a package, in most cases with its connections. 
If a package contains many connections(SQL or file or others), and every time you open the package, one has to wait several minutes for the validation to complete. If one wants to skip this, change the SSIS to work offline(SSIS->Work offline). This has no affect running the SSIS package as SQL Server Job. 
Otherwise, this validation is ALWAYS done automatically before the package executes. If the tasks have validation errors, the execution fails.
The only way I know to explicitly validate the SSIS package is from SSMS Integration Services Catalog. Here you can go to a particular SSIS package and right click on the package you need to validate. Of course, the package needs to be deployed for this.
[image]